# Django Session isn't getting updated appropriately

Tags: python, django, session

Stumbled upon the error message - **The request's session was deleted before the request completed. The user may have logged out in a concurrent request, for example.** This error is popping up when rendering a django template (narrowed down the error to the line - return render(request, {})). This process involves uploading a file, running view logic, and presenting the results to the user. It worked for a good many files and is throwing this error for one specific file. The view logic involves a bunch of django session updates. Suspected that this error could be due to the huge session size. Ironically though, the size of the session as I checked in the DB is 120 MB, which sounds reasonable.

Can you walk me through the possible issues that could have led to this error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you would have written 120kB, I'd say that might be a little bit large. You should reduce your session size and keep as much as possible in the requests!

Comment: Session is being stored in Postgres DB wherein the field size could be up to 1 GB. So how would this raise session-related error?

Comment: The whole session has to be loaded into every request. And obviously that is causing problems.

Comment: I'll have to access the current view's data in various other views. What would be the possible alternative to sharing data among multiple views?

Comment: It's hard to give an alternative if you didn't provide any code.

Comment: I don't think I can share the code in-here. :(
I'm using sessions to store some results from a database query. And thereby, using the same results on a different page that's being redirected to from the current page. User is also given options on the same page to perform some operations on the data presented on the page. So on choosing a specific operation, data manipulation specific to that operation is done and then the modified data is presented to the user.

Comment: That sounds like you are abusing the session as a cache.

Comment: Session can in turn use cache as its back-end. I don't think I'm 'abusing' session.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Klaus D. Will try to use a different mechanism to store data.